# Does Google index multiple divs on one page as multiple pages

Tags: html, search

For a customer we need to develop a website that contains projects with multiple pages. Sort of like a magazine. Our idea is to have multiple pages/slides and on each page we want to display an article (HTML/CSS). The product needs to be multi platform and we want to have the pages sliding. At this point we have created it but we now have one page with multiple DIVS (each DIV is a page). Each div has a H1 and an own link (/1 /2 /3 etc. for the slides) My question is, will Google search like and understand this and index it as different pages? Or will we need separate html pages for that?

Comment: Short answer - look at the URL. If the URL does not change (by something other than advanced scripts), then it's only 1 page for Google and then you should only have one H1 etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you just have the content on the page - no, it will treat it as one page.

However if you use HTML 5 pushstate or the 'Hashbang' method then there is a good chance crawlers will index them individually.

Try https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/

It allows you to change the url using HTML 5 pushstates, whilst keeping the user on the same page. It basically adds urls to the users history stack meaning they can use the back button on a single page site which is dynamic. It also has fallback for older browsers using the hashbang method (/#!/). This basically allows you to append to the url in the address bar, meaning when the user reloads your site, you can check what you should show them.

BTW, you can use more than h1 nowadays. In HTML 5 it is recommended to have a h1 per section.